# HTML content is not getting on Jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $("input#Addmore").click(function(){
        $('div#add_div').append("<a class='remove' href='#'>X</a>");
    });         
});
```

This code on click of add more button and I want to remove parent div of above added code on click of "X" by jquery. for that purpose i am using this code

```
$("a.remove").click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

But the code is not working because jQuery did not getting append anchor code. Can any one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delegate the event to the nearest static element. Try this:

```
$('#add_div').on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Or if you are using an older version of jQuery (less than 1.7) use `delegate()` like this:

```
$('#add_div').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: I must say there are some awesome programmers in our community and you are one of them :)..It Works...thnx a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#add_div').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
  $("input#Addmore").click(function(){
       $("div#add_div").append("<a class='remove' href='javascipt:;' onclick='remove(this);return false' href='#'>X<br/></a>");
});
```

and here is remove function:

```
 window.remove = function(obj)
   {
        $(obj).closest('div').remove();
   }
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/Hvx2u/3/